# RestKit: Map nested Array to Object

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have two classes to map a JSON response: `Item` and `FrequentProps`

Item has the following properties:

```
frequentProps, identifier, name
```

FrequentProps has the properties

```
propOne
propTwo
propThree
propFour
```

You can see that `frequentProps` in `Item` is of type `FrequentProps`.

Consider the following JSON Response:

```
[
    {
        "frequentProps": [
            {
                "propOne": 174
            },
            {
                "propTwo": 9.726
            },
            {
                "propThree": 2.021
            },
            {
                "propFour": 25.07
            }
        ],
        "identifier": "4223",
        "name": "TheName"
    }
]
```

The outer part of the JSON is supposed to be mapped to an object of class `Item`, the nested Array is supposed to be mapped to `frequentProps`, as a property of the object. Unfortunately, `frequentProps` is not mapped to the `Item`s property with the same name but into an `NSArray` (if I define the type of the property as `NSArray`, otherwise the property remains nil).

Here's the configuration:

```
RKObjectMapping *itemMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Item class]];
[item addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[Item attributesMapping]];
RKObjectMapping *frequentPropsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[FrequentProps class]];    
[frequentPropsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[FrequentProps attributesMapping]];
[itemMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"frequentProps"
                                                                                      toKeyPath:@"frequentProps"
                                                                                    withMapping:frequentProps]];

// adding the response descriptor, etc...
```

How can I map the `frequentProps` directly into an object of type `FrequentProps`, which remains a property of `Item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because there is no way in the mapping to specify that you are indexing into an array and putting that index into a specified key. I expect that this will never be supported.

Not ideal but: What you could do it to add the array property as well, with a custom setter method. When the setter is called, mutate the data by creating an instance of `FrequentProps` and setting the properties from the array contents.

Comment: I was afraid that this would be the case. Thanks for your suggestion, I had something like this in mind if there would be no designated use case in RestKit.